# Php yii2 404 Not found

Tags: php, yii, yii2, http-status-code-404, yii2-advanced-app

I'm new to yii and i'm trying to make the "Saying Hello" yii2 tutorial.
I have this on the site controller:

```
//Code
public function actionSay($message = 'Hello')
{
    return $this->render('say', ['message' => $message]);
}
//Code
```

And this on my say.php view:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
?>
<?= Html::encode($message) ?>
```

This is my project structure:
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSaq9.png)
However, when i try to access the site (configured as yii.local) to show the say action, i got a 404 Not Found.

```
http://yii.local/index.php?r=site%2Fsay&message=Hello+World
```

[404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1rge.png)

Anyone has any lead on this? Perhaps some documentation or step i missed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yii.local  is for backend ?   frontend?

Comment: frontend, perhaps it should be backend?

Comment: DocumentRoot C:\Apache24\htdocs\yii2\advanced\backend\web
ServerName yii.local

This is my config

Comment: you have site on internet for yii.local  or you are in localhost ?   ..

Comment: I am in localhost

Comment: then don't use  http://

Comment: It's the same, it does not throw 404 error anymore but it redirects to login page

Comment: then  you are in localhost  and yi2 work  .. for the redirect to login .. update your question  and add  the site/controller code   ..  please  .

Comment: maybe you didn't put `say.php` file inside `views/site/` ?

Comment: if you update the question and add your code  .. i can take a look  .. otherwise  ..  i can't imagine  .. where is the problem  ..

Comment: Please check inbult methods with site controller. site/about
Its working or not?

Comment: Please follow a good tutorial, there are many when you search in google.  You can configure 404, routes and a lots of things. First thing you have to test the framework is loading, then you can write custom codes etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller is Ok and The view file as well.

Please check the url you are trying to access.

Its: yii.local/

I think it should be http://localhost/rest_of_the_url

Answer (score 0):

I think in your controller should be like this:

```
public function actionSay($message){
     #code......
}
```

and the inside the link, the part after "message=" should be the message that you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

http://yii.local/index.php?r=site%2Fsay&message=Hello+World

why %2F? Yii2 may recognize it correctly.

http://yii.local/index.php?r=site/say&message=Hello+World doesn't work?